# Get the PID of a process to kill it, without knowing its full name

Tags: java, android, eclipse, process, kill

I'm coding an Android application. Now I'm going to a part where the application should kill a process. But I don't know its full name or its PID. I Know the commands:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(Pid)
```

and

```
android.os.Process.getUidForName("com.android.email")
```

But my problem is that I don't know the full name of the process.

It's an native code process, so not something like com.something.something

The process is `/data/data/com.something.something/mybinary`

but it's running with commands like

```
/data/data/com.something.something/mybinary -a 123 -b 456
```

because of this I can't use

```
android.os.Process.getUidForName("/data/data/com.something.something/mybinary")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> services = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
 String service1name = services[1].processName;
```

You can get all running process's package names, check which one you want to kill, choose that process get process id by service.pid.

And call:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(service.pid);
```

Comment: But how do you initialize manager object, I could not figure out.

Comment: ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

this is the way how you initialize it.

Comment: Not get process from /data/data/com.something.something/mybinary

Comment: With killProcess(pid) you can only kill a process that you created, as per documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29. Use ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName) to kill another app's process.

Answer (score 2):

your process name is '/data/data/com.something.something/mybinary'
first get process id of the native process running by parsing output of top and then use android.os.Process.killProcess(Pid)

```
             import org.apache.commons.exec.*;
             import java.io.IOException;
        public class NativeKillerRunnable implements Runnable {
             private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NativeKillerRunnable.class);
          @Override
                public void run() {
        String commandtoexec = "top -n 1 -m 100";
        CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(commandtoexec);
       DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        try {
           PumpStreamHandler psh = new PumpStreamHandler(new LogOutputStream() {
            @Override
            protected void processLine(String s, int i) {
                s = s.trim();
      //check for name of your binary process 
                if(s.contains("mybinary"))
                {
                    String[] strings = s.split(" ");
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(Integer.parseInt(strings[0]));
                    logger.info("killed mybinary process with pid = "+strings[0]);
                }
            }
        });
        executor.setStreamHandler(psh);
        executor.execute(cmdLine);
    } catch (ExecuteException executeException) {
        logger.error("caught exception while killing mybinary process "+executeException.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem.Finally,I find a method to kill my binary process with android java code.
first,write process info to a txt file:

```
echo `ps | grep /data/data/com.something.something/mybinary` > /sdcard/pid.txt
```

and then,use java code to read this file,you could get String like:

```
root 17857 16409 87568 14880 ffffffff aaf0ec68 R /data/data/com.something.something/mybinary
```

you have got the pid of your process, execute kill command in java.

Answer (score -1):

You can do smth like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps");
p.waitFor();
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
int ch;
char [] buf = new char[1024];
while((ch = isr.read(buf)) != -1)
{
    sb.append(buf, 0, ch);
}
HashMap pMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
String [] processLinesAr = sb.toString().split("\n");
for(String line : processLinesAr)
{
    String [] comps = line.split("[\\s]+");
    if(comps.length != 9)
    return;         
    pid = Integer.parseInt(comps[1]);
    packageName = comps[8];
    pMap.put(packageName, pid);
    //...
}
```

Then you can parse sb and get pid of your process.

Comment: yuri im doing this method to check if my process is running with:

if(sb.toString().indexOf("data/data/myprocess") > 0)

but how can i parse the sb to get the pid of the process, i know that the pid is behind the process name but how can i extract it

Comment: mhh i got it extracted the pid made it an integer but im trying to kill it with 

android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);

but it didn't worked. when im killing myself with:

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

it works but with another pid not :S

Comment: This is unsafe, because `ps` can have different outputs with toolbox or busybox versions etc.