# How to get the PID from PS command output in Android shell

Tags: android, shell

Can anyone tell how can I get the PID from the output of PS command in Android shell.
For example from the output:

```
u0_a51    20240 38    132944 22300 ffffffff 40037ebc S com.example.poc_service
```

pid value `20240` is to be got. I tried

```
ps -ef | grep com.example.poc_service
```

but to no avail. Also `pgrep` is not being recognized.

Comment: What is "keyword", i.e. what are you searching in ps output? (it's easy to isolate PID column, I would go with `ps | awk '{print $2}'`)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anton. But it throws the error** awk not found..** Seems Android shell doesn't support all of the linux commands

Comment: Try `ps -C com.example.poc_service -o pid=` (note capital `-C`. No, i'm unsure whether it works)

Comment: this also not working :(

Comment: Although my solution was not accepted you can check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625212/java-android-get-pid-from-process-name-but-dont-know-its-full-name/8625458#8625458

Answer (score 3):

If you have shell access in Android you can also use `pidof`:

```
# pidof com.example.poc_service
20240
```

However, be careful as there may be multiple processes matching...

Comment: This looks promising, but when I run it, I get a bunch of pids back, starting with "1 2 3 6...". Any clue what's going on?

Comment: @JohannesBrodwall Did you get any substitute for this?

Comment: @JohannesBrodwall Probably because the process is running on multiple threads. It could also be that it started a bunch of sub-processes.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty nasty but it works:

```
for pid in `ls /proc`; do 
   cmd=`cat $pid/cmdline 2> /dev/null`;

   if [ "X$cmd" == "Xcom.example.poc_service" ]; then
       echo $pid;
   fi 
done
```

or as one line:

```
for pid in `ls /proc`; do cmd=`cat $pid/cmdline 2> /dev/null`; if [ "X$cmd" == "X/system/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon" ]; then echo $pid; fi done
```

Comment: Nice Solution. Adding a break after echo $pid; will make it more efficient though.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `grep`, `egrep`, `fgrep`, `rgrep` is available in Android.

If you are working on `Unix`, `Linux`, `Mac` or `Cygwin`, you can pipe the output of `adb shell` command to get the result you want.

```
$ adb shell ps |grep settings
system    23846 71    111996 22676 ffffffff 00000000 S com.android.settings
$ adb shell ps |grep settings |awk '{print $2}'
23846
```